# Can 2 pieces of metals combine after long time contact?

Tags: metal

Does 2 pieces of metals combine automatically after long time contact because of atom vibration and collision and finally form metallic bonds between the contact surface?

Comment: Well, they kinda can, but the surface must be really exceptionally clean.

Comment: See, this has been answered before: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/why-dont-metals-bond-when-touched-together

Comment: Interestingly, in space if two metals make contact, they will automatically combine to form one metal

Comment: Gold will bond to gold  in a short time, and only a bit longer is needed when in contact with silver or copper. Indium also can bond quickly. BTW, I've had mercury wet a gold ring, leaving a silver-colored stain, that disappeared in a few days as the mercury flowed deeper into the ring.